# Navigation Link Set deployment issue from Dev to Sandbox Account

Tags: community, sandbox, navigation, unmanaged-package, digital-experience

I'm trying install an unmanaged Package from my dev org to a Sandbox org using the Package installation Link. The Package contains the Digital Experience Sites (communities) and a related dependency is   Navigation Link Set.

**The installation is failing with error**: (CommunityPage_Default_User_Profile_Menu) Too many retries of batch save in the presence of Apex triggers with failures: when triggers are present partial save requires that some subset of rows save without any errors in order to avoid inconsistent side effects from those triggers. Number of retries: 2

CommunityPage_Default_User_Profile_Menu -> Name of the Navigation Link Set.

I tried to install the same version of the package to another dev org and the the package got installed without any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the root cause for the issue was that no community licences were present in the sandbox and as a result  Navigation Link Set was failing because it for the community page.